# Arrange data in a List

Tags: java, collections

I have a List that stores ID and date. ID can be repeated in the system.
I need the date to be added to the already existing id.

```
List<Logs> newList = Stream.of (firstFileLog, second)
.flatMap (Collection::stream)
.collect (Collectors.toList ());
System.out.println (newList);

input data-> 
[{id='1', time=15.01.2021}
, {id='2', time=12.05.2021}
, {id='3', time=14.02.2021}
, {id='4', time=11.05.2022}
, {id='1', time=30.09.2012}
, {id='2', time=02.01.2021}
, {id='1', time=18.02.2024}
]
```

i want to get this

```
   > output data -> [{id='1', time=15.01.2021, time=30.09.2012,
    > time=18.02.2024} , {id='2', time=12.05.2021, time=02.01.2021} ,
    > {id='3', time=14.02.2021} , {id='4', time=11.05.2022} ]
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Seems like the right job for a dictionary or map, e.g. HashMap<Integer, List<YourDateClass>>. Simply check if an id exists, if it doesn't add an empty array for that id, no else, then add your date to that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by your `id` map to your `time` and collect the values to list. Assuming you have the apropriate getters for `id` and `time`:

```
Stream.of(firstFileLog, second)
        .flatMap (Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Logs::getId,
                 Collectors.mapping(Logs::getTime,Collectors.toList())))
        .entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

to get an output like:

```
1=[15.01.2021, 30.09.2012, 18.02.2024]
2=[12.05.2021, 02.01.2021]
3=[14.02.2021]
4=[11.05.2022]
```